# What will happen if a dependent voltage source in parallel with a dependent current source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source

What will happen if a dependent voltage source in parallel with a dependent current source.

like dependent voltage source: 4Vx and current source 3Ix in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Your current source would force current through the voltage source.

Comment: Depends where Ix and Vx are measured from.

Comment: I have added an example now in the question now,that way i can understand it i think

Comment: There is no X but you have two opposing dependent current sources that may be converted to Thevenin equivalents to solve to see if there is an equilibrium or not. Very academic.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem at all with connecting a voltage source and a current source in parallel.

The current source just increases or decreases the amount of current the voltage source has to supply to drive its output to its defined output voltage.

This is true whether the sources are independent or dependent types.

In your circuit, the problem is that you have the output of the VCVS being across the exact same terminals as its controlling input. The voltage \$V_{ab}\$ can't be simultaneously V2 and V2/5000 at the same time.

There is a trivial solution \$V_2=0\$, but if you wanted a short circuit between a and b, you should have just drawn a short circuit there.

Comment: If an independent voltage source in parallel will independent current source we can remove the current source and keep voltage source only ,so here can i do the same ? Because in parallel voltage is same accros the terminals

Comment: Yes, you can remove the CCCS and it won't change anything except how much current flows through the VCVS.